# Plan for retiring 2007 Edge Transport

Tags: exchange, migration

I'm doing an Exchange 2007->2010 migration, for one domain in a multi-domain org. Got all the mailboxes moved already, all users connecting to 2010 CAS array (also HT role on those, no Edge in the 2010 environment). 2007 still has its edge transport server.

Can I just add a Send Connector for * to the 2010 HT servers, to start the retirement of the 2007 Edge server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the answer is "Yes, but if there are other HT servers on the same Edge subscription, the Edge server will continue to be used by those other HT servers, of course." I didn't check and had an unexpected HT server in the org.